# HTML/CSS: Mysterious Blank Space

Tags: html, css

Currently I have been encountering a problem with my website where there is a mysterious blank space at the top of my website that is not attributed to any specific div or HTML item. This is happening on all my pages and my usual guides are as dumbstruck as I to this problem.

Alas, I cannot give code snippets of the issue because I don't know where the problem is being made *however* I do have a live version of the website available.

Live version of issue: [sch242.comeze.com](http://sch242.comeze.com/index.php)

If anyone can figure out the reason for this I would be very appreciative. I cannot find another topic similar to this on stackoverflow already.

Comment: It's coming from `margin-bottom: 6em;` on the `<nav>` element. Also the bottom margin on `header, main, #sidebar {  margin-bottom: 5px; }`

Comment: your html and css code please

Comment: You might want to add a doctype to your markup as well:

`<!doctype html>`

Comment: @Spr `Firebug` - https://getfirebug.com/

Comment: You have fixed your website, but now this question is not helpful to anyone else since the problem can no longer be reproduced...

Comment: @Marc How would you suggest I post in future? I'm very new to all this and I had no idea where the problem would be in this particular dilemma. I thought that posting 300 lines of messy code would be innappropriate and more succinct lines of code or a working model would be appreciated moreso.

Comment: The original problem had to do with the `nav` bar in the `<header>`, so posting the `<header>` code and the `.splitter-bar` would have been enough, along with the CSS.  I appreciate the dilemma and this is a common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove margin-bottom from `<nav id="menu">` CSS

```
nav {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    margin-bottom: 6em; //Remove this property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main.css the following class giving this issue.

```
nav {
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #333333;
margin-bottom: 6em; /* Issue line*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

your nav style has a margin-bottom. If you remove it will stick to the top.

```
nav {
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #333333;
/*margin-bottom: 6em;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

main.css file

```
nav {
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #333333;
margin-bottom: 2em; /* this will make it look better */
}
```